# NHibernate Insert into ... select ... with GUID as PrimaryKey

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I try to do fallowing with NHibernate:

```
this.Session.CreateQuery(@"insert into ContactGroupContact (Id, MailAddress, Company, Person, Branch, ContactGroup, User, FaxNumber)
                             select newid(), MailAddress, Company, Person, Branch, 
                                    :destContactGroupId, User, FaxNumber
                             from ContactGroupContact cgc
                             where cgc.ContactGroup.Id = :contactGroupId")
        .SetEntity("destContactGroupId", tempContactGroup)
        .SetGuid("contactGroupId", contactGroupId)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
```

The column `Id` of `ContactGroupContact` is of type `GUID`.

When I execute this, I get a `NHibernate.QueryException` with the following message:

> No data type for node: MethodNode ( ( newid exprList ) [insert into
>   ContactGroupContact (Id, MailAddress, Company, Person, Branch,
>   ContactGroup, User, FaxNumber)
>    select newid(), MailAddress, Company, Person, Branch, :destContactGroupId, User, FaxNumber
>    from ContactGroupContact cgc
>    where cgc.ContactGroup.Id = :contactGroupId]

Can someone help me, what is going wrong? - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a derived `Dialect` and registering `newid` as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Diego's suggestion. I admit I am new to this, but assuming this is the appropriate way to handle it (it works)

```
public class DerivedDialectWithNewId : MsSql2005Dialect
{
    public DerivedDialectWithNewId()
    {
        RegisterFunction("newid", new NoArgSQLFunction("newid", NHibernateUtil.Guid, true));        
    }
}
```

and here is how to use it with Fluent NHibernate

```
private static FluentConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(
                    c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("CustomConnectionString"))
                    .Dialect<DerivedDialectWithNewId>()));
    }
```

Comment: How would you call this using LINQ?